# CakePHP 3 routing resource with different name

Tags: cakephp, routes, nested-resources, cakephp-3.0

I am creating REST API using Cake resource. I have route for users:

> /users

and now I want to create nested resource for users on projects

> /projects/:projectId/users

However I don't want to use UsersController for this one, I want to use different controller. My routing looks like this:

```
$routes->resources('Users');
$routes->resources('Projects', function ($routes) {
    $routes->resources('Members');
});
```

I don't know how to set up that the route for MembersControlles is not members but users.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to create that type of alias, although I think it could be very useful. Try opening a enhancement request ticket in github.

Answer (score 1):

There are no aliases for resources from memory. The string passed to the resource is the controller name. So passing 'Members', CakePHP is going to look for the MembersController. But your Entity is obviously called User and your controller is UsersController? Which should contain your index, add, edit, delete methods for the RESTful API.
To create an alias you could try inheritance, you could create a MembersController and have it extend your UsersController?

Comment: Well the problem is, that I don't want to have just alias but also different functionality. MembersController index returns list of users that are connected with the project, but UsersController returns list of all users, also MembersController delete just remove the user from the project, not delete him, etc. So I don't know how inheritance could help me with that.

Comment: I see, sorry it was just the way you explained it. I'm assuming you have a join table between Users and Projects something like users_projects ? with a HasManyAndBelongsToMany relationship defined ?